# Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose $|K|^2 \nmid |G|$, show $K$ is characteristic subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Suppose $|K|^2 \nmid |G|$ and $K$ is simple, Prove $G$ does not have any subgroup isomorphic to $K$ except $K$. Show $K$ is a characteristic subgroup.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups then $HK$ is  a normal subgroup and $|HK|=\frac{|H| \cdot |K|}{|H \cap K|}$.

Comment: SO is this correct? If $G$ has a subgroup $H$ isomorphic to $K$ then $H$ is normal in $G$. So it suffices to check that normal subgroup of $G$  is different from $K$ is not isomorphic to $K$. Given H, $H\cap K$ is normal in both $H$ and $K$.  But since $K$ is simple, if $H$ is no-trivial, then $|H\cap K|$ is $K$. and $|HK|$=$|H|$ Hence that means any normal subgroup of $G$ that is not trivial of $K$ contains $K$.  And $K$ is characteristic because automorphism preserve subgroups? and since there is only one subgroup Isomorphic to $K$, namely $K$, then it has to be fixed by any automorphism.

Comment: You wrote: "If G has a subgroup H isomorphic to K then H is normal in G". This does not have to be true (look at the subgroups of order $2$ or $D_4$, the dihedral group of order $8$.). If $\alpha \in Aut(G)$, the for the $K$ in your post $\alpha(K)$ IS normal in $G$ and so is $\alpha(K) \cap K$ in $K$. The simplicity of $K$ yields $\alpha(K) \cap K=K$ or $=1$. In the latter case use the formula to arrive at a contradiction. The first case yields $K \subseteq \alpha(K)$ and since $|K|=|\alpha(K)|$, the sets must be equal. Hence $\alpha$ fixes $K$ and $K$ char $G$.